# Javascript - outer reference of a function shows "not defined"

Tags: javascript, scope, undefined

i have the following code:

```
function log(a) {
    var b = 5;
    a();

}

log(function(){
    console.log(b);
});
```

When that anon function is executed at function log, I am getting "b is not defined". Well, It seems like that anon's outer environment reference isn't log's, as If it wasn't created inside of it so therefore it can't find that var. so where is it being created? on the global level? My initial thought was that those parentheses make the anon function created inside of log's.

Comment: JavaScript uses Lexical scoping, so it is the place where you define the function that decide what variable names that you have access to. Read up on "Lexical scope" vs "Dynamic scope".

Comment: Well in this case, where is it sitting lexically?

Comment: We can't tell, from this snippet alone. But at least not inside of "function log".

Comment: @user2081462: Yes, it's sitting in the global lexical scope. It is created where the function expression is evaluated, not where it is called.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call a function, assuming that you do not declare global variables (you didn't declared any), the scope is created for that function and what goes in that scope is determined not by where the function was **called** but by where it was **defined**. You can see that where you defined the anonymous function (in the call to log), the variable `b` is not in that scope that is why it's not available.

Let's rewrite your code:

```
function log(a) {
    var b = 5;
    a();  
}
function logger() {
    console.log(b);
}
log(logger);
```

You can see that your code and mine are doing the same thing, the only difference is that mine code doesn't have an anon function. They do not share common variables in their scopes.

Now check this out:

```
var b = 5;
function log(a) {
    a();  
}
function logger() {
    console.log(b);
}
log(logger);
```

Now both log and logger share a common variable b in their scopes (log is not using b so if you check it in a debugger it will be undefined). As I say you don't determine scope by where function was called but by where and how it was declared.

Comment: Thank you, so we can say that anon function sits at the global level, because it was created before log function was finally executed?

Comment: @user2081462: It's not so much important that there was this call to `log`, but more that the current scope at that time was the global one. If you didn't use an anonymous function but rather declared it in front of `log(…)` it might be more obvious

Comment: user2081462. No I didn't say that. Both functions sit at the same level. I updated my answer so I hope it's more clear what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript scopes exists within functions. So your b variable is visible only within its scope - the anonymous function. If you want it to be visible outside the function then you can assign the variable to the global scope.

```
function log(a) {
    window.b = 5;
    a();
}

log(function(){
    console.log(b);
});
```

Comment: Please don't do that. Just use a function parameter and pass it as an argument.

Comment: Just played with his code for him to understand. Nobody said that it's a perfect legit production ready code.